# Is LINQ slower than foreach loop for aggregation operations?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, foreach

***The short question***: Why is LINQ slower than looping via foreach for aggregation operations?

**Description -**

I am trying to optimize some old code and while LINQ queries are used extensively throughout the code, trivial operations like summing up numbers in an `Enumerable` is done using loops.

So, I ran a little test to compare the performance of the two methods. **Below is the code for computing sum of a 1000 numbers long enumerable using LINQ's `.Sum()` method and using a `foreach` loop and summing up each occurence manually.**

```
List<Double> numbers = new List<Double>();
Double[] sums1 = new Double[1000];
Double[] sums2 = new Double[1000];

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(i * i);
}

Int64 startTime1 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Double sum = 0;
    sum = numbers.Sum();
    sums1[i] = sum;
}
Int64 endTime1 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

Int64 startTime2 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Double sum = 0;
    foreach (Double number in numbers)
    {
        sum += number;
    }
    sums2[i] = sum;
}
Int64 endTime2 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

Console.WriteLine("LINQ.    Start = {0}, End = {1}: Diff = {2}", startTime1, endTime1, endTime1 - startTime1);
Console.WriteLine("ForEach. Start = {0}, End = {1}: Diff = {2}", startTime2, endTime2, endTime2 - startTime2);
```

I ran this test a couple (ten) times and the results were:

```
LINQ.    Start = 117385428996, End = 117385462197: Diff = 33201
Foreach. Start = 117385462203, End = 117385476329: Diff = 14126
LINQ.    Start = 117385478555, End = 117385499802: Diff = 21247
Foreach. Start = 117385499808, End = 117385520756: Diff = 20948
LINQ.    Start = 117385521426, End = 117385546256: Diff = 24830
Foreach. Start = 117385546260, End = 117385567052: Diff = 20792
LINQ.    Start = 117385572791, End = 117385602149: Diff = 29358
Foreach. Start = 117385602156, End = 117385622367: Diff = 20211
LINQ.    Start = 117385623153, End = 117385652563: Diff = 29410
Foreach. Start = 117385652568, End = 117385673733: Diff = 21165
LINQ.    Start = 117385674403, End = 117385705028: Diff = 30625
Foreach. Start = 117385705035, End = 117385725552: Diff = 20517
LINQ.    Start = 117385726094, End = 117385753161: Diff = 27067
Foreach. Start = 117385753166, End = 117385771824: Diff = 18658
LINQ.    Start = 117385772341, End = 117385793726: Diff = 21385
Foreach. Start = 117385793733, End = 117385811332: Diff = 17599
LINQ.    Start = 117385811768, End = 117385837204: Diff = 25436
Foreach. Start = 117385837209, End = 117385852670: Diff = 15461
LINQ.    Start = 117385853003, End = 117385874410: Diff = 21407
Foreach. Start = 117385874416, End = 117385891874: Diff = 17458
```

Note that the `foreach` loop always performed better. What could be the reason for this?

Edit: An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4045801/1750620) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044400/linq-performance-faq) has lot of good information about why the performance could be bad as compared to regular inline manipulations. But I am unable to see how exactly it could relate here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ performance FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044400/linq-performance-faq)

Comment: I added a look with `for (int x = 0; x < numbers.Count; x++)` and it's between LINQ and foreach

Comment: BTW. You code logs `ForEach` and the results have `Foreach`. Magic ;)

Comment: Of course you ran this test in release mode with optimization, didn't you?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I ran this with and without optimization, in debug as well as release mode. The numbers changed, the pattern did not.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: I just read the possible duplicate you suggested, if I serached a little more I would've found it. Thank you for the suggestion. 
While It answers most of my questions about performance with LINQ, none of the reasons given over there apply to this particular situation.
I am trying to create an extension method myself to better understand the situation. I will update if I find something.

Comment: Linq is doing dynamic parsing while the for loop is using fixed compiled code.  Dynamic solutions always are slower then compiled code which is optimized.

Comment: Linq doesn't need to be faster as  It also uses loops internally.

Comment: Try using a simple `for` loop instead of a `foreach`. I expect the for loop to be faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it is about what you are iterating. I slightly changed your code. First it is iterating over IEnumerable (which you say `linq`), and then iterating over List (which you say `foreach`). **I got the same results with you.**

Please check the methods `withIEnumerable` and `withList`. They do exactly the same thing except that signatures are different. LINQ extension methods gets `IEnumerable` as parameter.

Edit: [Performance between Iterating through IEnumerable<T> and List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536541/performance-between-iterating-through-ienumerablet-and-listt) gives a good explanation why list enumerates faster.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            calculate();
        }

    }

    private static void calculate()
    {
        List<Double> numbers = new List<Double>();
        Double[] sums1 = new Double[1000];
        Double[] sums2 = new Double[1000];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i * i);
        }

        Int64 startTime1 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            sums1[i] = withIEnumerable(numbers);
        }
        Int64 endTime1 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

        Int64 startTime2 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            sums2[i] = withList(numbers);
        }
        Int64 endTime2 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();


        Console.WriteLine("withIEnumerable.    Start = {0}, End = {1}: Diff = {2}", startTime1, endTime1, endTime1 - startTime1);
        Console.WriteLine("withList. Start = {0}, End = {1}: Diff = {2}", startTime2, endTime2, endTime2 - startTime2);
    }

    private static double withIEnumerable(IEnumerable<double> numbers)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        foreach (Double number in numbers)
        {
            sum += number;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    private static double withList(List<double> numbers)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        foreach (Double number in numbers)
        {
            sum += number;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> *This is not the correct answer, but I'm going to leave it here for
>   reference instead of deleting it. Please read serdar's answer (the
>   accepted one). Please let me know or edit if this is against the way the commnunity works.*

Calling the methods have an added very prominent time overhead. 
From what I have found, this is the biggest contributor to the slower performance in this particular case.

I added an extension method to sum up the list with the same (faster) code, but inside an extension method.

```
public static class MyExtensionMethods
{
    public static Double SumX(this IEnumerable<Double> list)
    {
        Double sum = 0;
        foreach (Double number in list)
        {
            sum += number;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

And then using the extension method I just created,

```
...
Int64 startTime2 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    Double sum = numbers.SumX();
    sums2[i] = sum;
}
Int64 endTime2 = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
...
```

The results were:

```
LINQ.    Start = 129087370675, End = 129087395309: Diff = 24634
Foreach. Start = 129087395312, End = 129087420320: Diff = 25008
LINQ.    Start = 129087422887, End = 129087447541: Diff = 24654
Foreach. Start = 129087447547, End = 129087465859: Diff = 18312
LINQ.    Start = 129087466278, End = 129087484777: Diff = 18499
Foreach. Start = 129087484784, End = 129087505378: Diff = 20594
LINQ.    Start = 129087506425, End = 129087526134: Diff = 19709
Foreach. Start = 129087526141, End = 129087552013: Diff = 25872
LINQ.    Start = 129087552500, End = 129087578445: Diff = 25945
Foreach. Start = 129087578451, End = 129087601858: Diff = 23407
LINQ.    Start = 129087602371, End = 129087630873: Diff = 28502
Foreach. Start = 129087630880, End = 129087674495: Diff = 43615
LINQ.    Start = 129087675028, End = 129087702841: Diff = 27813
Foreach. Start = 129087702849, End = 129087732360: Diff = 29511
LINQ.    Start = 129087732974, End = 129087760529: Diff = 27555
Foreach. Start = 129087760536, End = 129087785590: Diff = 25054
LINQ.    Start = 129087786096, End = 129087813331: Diff = 27235
Foreach. Start = 129087813336, End = 129087842947: Diff = 29611
LINQ.    Start = 129087843471, End = 129087870633: Diff = 27162
Foreach. Start = 129087870639, End = 129087896678: Diff = 26039
```

> **Bottom Line: LINQ is slower in this case because of the added overhead of the extension methods. I also tried using a simple static method instead of the extension method, and its weren't results any different that the results with extension method.**

Comment: What was the input parameter of your static method? IEnumerable<double> or List<double>? I think it was List<double>. Try the other please.

Comment: Now, any idea why is IEnumerable list iterating slower than the List?

Comment: Thank you for accepting. In fact I did not know that it is iterating slower than list. But I just tried to localize the issue and then saw the situation. Please share if you find any reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23536541/performance-between-iterating-through-ienumerablet-and-listt gives a good explenation why list enumerates faster.