# IEnumerable<> vs List<> as a parameter

Tags: c#, performance, ienumerable, benchmarking

In general I tend to use `IEnumerable<>` as the type when I pass in parameters. However according to BenchmarkDotNet:

```
[Benchmark]
public void EnumeratingCollectionsBad()
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Bad(list);
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public void EnumeratingCollectionsFixed()
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Fixed(list);
    }
}

private static void Bad(IEnumerable<string> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
    }
}

private static void Fixed(List<string> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
    }
}
```

| Method | Job | Runtime | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EnumeratingCollectionsBad | .NET Core 3.1 | .NET Core 3.1 | 17.802 us | 0.3670 us | 1.0764 us | 17.338 us | 6.3782 | - | - | 40032 B |
| EnumeratingCollectionsFixed | .NET Core 3.1 | .NET Core 3.1 | 5.015 us | 0.1003 us | 0.2535 us | 4.860 us | - | - | - | 32 B |

Why would the interface version be so much slower (and memory intensive) than the concrete version?

Comment: @UnholySheep: That's at least not the *majority* of what's going on here.

Comment: @GSerg: Nope, that's not a dupe of this one either. That refers to iterating over different types - here there's a `List<string>` (and an empty one at that) in both cases.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't see enumeration of different types being compared there? The [most upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51602520/11683) also looks pretty much like yours.

Comment: @GSerg: Nope: "What we know about List<T> is that it is an in-memory collection, so the MoveNext() function on its enumerator is going to be very cheap. It looks like your collection gives an enumerator whose MoveNext() method is more expensive, perhaps because it is interacting with some external resource such as a database connection."

Comment: @GSerg: In other words, the *actual type of the iterable at execution time* is different in that question, whereas in this case the actual type is `List<string>` in both cases.

Comment: @JonSkeet That's a quote from the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23536909/11683), not the [most upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51602520/11683)? Although yes, I do now see your point about different types. Still, IMO the most upvoted answer applies?

Comment: @GSerg: Ah, yes, I see what you mean now; sorry for not looking at the right answer. But I'd still say it's not a duplicate *question* - that most upvoted answer actually looks to be irrelevant to the question being asked, IMO. It states facts, but they're not the important ones for *that* question, whereas they're the important ones on *this* question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> Why would the interface version be so much slower (and memory intensive) than the concrete version?

When it uses the interface, the iteration has to allocate an object on the heap... whereas [`List<T>.GetEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getenumerator?view=net-5.0) returns a `List<T>.Enumerator`, which is a struct, and doesn't require any additional allocation. `List<T>.Enumerator` implements `IEnumerator<T>`, but because the compiler knows about the concrete type directly, it doesn't need to be boxed.

So even though both methods are operating on an object of the same type (a `List<T>`) one calls this method:

```cs
IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
```

... and one calls this:

```cs
List<T>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
```

The first almost certainly just delegates to the second, but has to box the result because `IEnumerator<T>` is a reference type.

The fact that `List<T>.GetEnumerator()` returns a mutable struct [can have some surprising consequences](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/07/27/iterate-damn-you/) but it's designed precisely to have the performance benefit you're seeing here.

The use of an interface vs a concrete type *can* itself have some very minor performance penalties, but the primary cause here is the difference in allocation.

Comment: @00110001: No, that's not the difference. That wouldn't affect allocation. The difference is in whether the iterator is boxed or not.

Comment: I failed the quiz in the [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/07/27/iterate-damn-you/ "Iterate, damn you!"). :-)

Comment: I use `IEnumerable<T>` for parameters to indicate that the collection is read only and can't be added to/removed from (though it's not good enough to stop people from modifying objects in the collection...)

Comment: @ldam: And that's almost always fine - but it does come with a performance penalty, as abstraction often does.